# Why doesn’t this hyperlink work as written here?

Tags: html, css

Following is html code.  The final div is a hyperlink that calls javascript.  This is the bottom of a longer page, but everything works until the final hyperlink, which appears on the page but not as a clickable link.

```html
<div style="padding-left:15%;">
  <a href="#" onclick="Showpages(18);" class="tfl" style="text-decoration:none; color:rgb(255,255,255)"><span class="blank">Action Hyperlink</span></a>
</div><br>

<div class="sp_01 bordered">
  <ul class="sp_03 bordered">
    <li class="sp_03 bordered" style="text-align:justify;">Text 1</li><br>
    <li class="sp_03 bordered" style="text-align:justify;">Text 2</li><br>
    <li class="sponsor_03 bordered" style="text-align:justify;">Text 3</li>
  </ul>
</div><br><br>

<div style="padding-left:15%;">
  <a href="#" onclick="ShowPages(18);" class="tfl" style="text-decoration: none;  color:rgb(255,255,255)"><span class="blank">Action Hyperlink</span></a>
</div><br>
```

The first instance of the hyperlink works.  After the -div class="sp_01 bordered"- section, the final instance of the hyperlink appears as a line but not a click link.

This sort of problem is usually related to how the preceding tags are open and closed.  I’ve studied the open and close tags and I don’t see anything wrong.  The color coding in my editor (Atom) is correct for all tags.

What’s wrong?

Comment: Is there CSS being applied that you haven't included? Perhaps something is overlapping. If you right click on the link and do *Inspect*, what do you see? Although it's white-on-white, your example seems fine. Without being able to replicate the issue, we can't diagnose it.

Comment: In the snippet you posted it is a clickable link, so we cannot reproduce your issue. Hard to see where it is though, because the text is styled the same color as the background.

Comment: I'll check it in the dev console.

Comment: As an interesting twist, this works in Chrome, but not in Firefox.

Comment: It works on both to me. It's just white on a white background, but that's all the issues I can see.

Comment: Since it works in Chrome but not in Firefox, I solved the issue by wrapping it in a box like in the code above it.  These cross-browser mysteries drive me nuts sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap your `DIV` inside `a` like

```
  <a href="#" onclick="ShowPages(18);" class="tfl" style="text-decoration: none;    color:rgb(255,255,255)"><span class="blank">Action Hyperlink</span>
    <div style="padding-left:15%;">

    </div>
 </a>
<br>
```

**Edit**

For future references this answer don't include sufficient information . So that I was trying to delete this. But after answer beign accepted it cant be deleted.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that helpful answer.  It works beautifully.  That's new to me -- wrap the div inside the anchor tag instead of the other way around.

Comment: What was the issue? What is the purpose of moving the `<div>` inside the `<a>`? How does it fix the problem? I have a feeling that there is no discernible answer to any one of those questions.

Comment: Even more puzzling is why Chrome had no problem with my original question but Firefox did.  Sometimes web development seems like a black art.

Comment: @RTC222 My point is that the question and answer, at this point, are both completely off-topic. The question doesn't replicate or show any issue at all, in any browser. The answer is a random-at-best reassortment of HTML elements. It doesn't seem to have a purpose, nor did they explain their reasoning or *why* this would solve the issue. I mean, consider it yourself: Your question was "Why isn't my hyperlink working?". Did this really answer that for you?

Comment: @RTC222 I need to test something. So that give e couple of minutes. I’ll add a complete answer

Comment: @NipunTharuksha The code that OP has shared does not have any issues in it, so trying to solve it will be like trying to fix a car that isn't broken. The true issue at-hand is something that has been omitted from the question.

Comment: @TylerRoper I know it. I'll update my answer. I think there is a issue with version compatability. But before go for any futher I need to test . Then Ill update my answer

Comment: Because it was broken on Firefox 67 but not on Chrome, I used his code.  It looks potentially like a browser error, not a coding error, because the original question was based on a link format I have used elsewhere with no problems.  As it stands, I can't see any reason why it shouldn't work and Chrome confirms that.  On Firefox it worked sporadically, but that's not good enough.  However the answer from @Nipun Tharuksha does work flawlessly.  I can't tell what's the magic of it but it solves the problem.

Comment: I can assure you that an `<a>` tag being wrapped in a `<div>` will not be an issue in any browser since the late 1990s. In fact, wrapping a `<div>` in an `<a>` tag is only syntactically acceptable since HTML5, so this code is less "compatible" than OP's. @RTC222 I understand that the issue isn't present when you use this code, my point is that something is obviously wrong somewhere else. This isn't solving the issue, it's just hiding it. If that's good enough for you then so be it. Though the question is likely to be deleted as it's of no use to future readers.

Comment: @TylerRoper yeah I it’s true. I have tested this . Even I can’t imagine what’s happening . RTC222 sorry I even can’t understand the process inside

Comment: @TylerRoper thanks . I have deleted the answer. Actually I should care more before answer again. If any of you guys find solution for this please update a proper answer for future references.